# Is http://sensormonkey.eeng.nuim.ie/ down? I need it for my sensors to work in the web

Tags: stream, arduino, sensors, monkey

Last month, I have found sensormonkey which is a great website for streaming live sensor data from arduino via webpage. However when I accessed the website this morning, I received an HTTP 504 ERROR.  http://sensormonkey.eeng.nuim.ie/

Is it just me? or my location(here in the Philippines)?

I need it to stream data from my sensor. Is there other ways that I could do these too using other websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes Sensormonkey is down and is probably going to stay down. The creators(myself and Aaron McCoy) have left academia to pursue other projects.  We might bring it back in another form in the future but for now we are focussing on distributed deep stack signal processing for wearable health sensors. As an alternative you could try [Xively](https://xively.com/)?

Comment: Great thanks to both of you.... Sensormonkey was awesome. If it wasn't down last year, I would have not studied its framework to complete my project from scratch. In fact I won our school's exposition with that project. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ is helpful to see if a website is down, and it appears it is.

As for streaming your sensor data I'm not aware of any service that does this, however if you explain more how youre using the service a work around that doesn't require a 3rd party service might be achievable.

Comment: Thanks for the info. and oh well,  my project became a little complex now that I have built everything from scratch - From sockets to real-time sensor streaming. If only the website wasn't down.